# How to plot a heatmap-like plot for categorical features?

Tags: python, statistics, visualization, categorical-data, heatmap

I would greatly appreciate let me know how to plot a `heatmap`-like plot for categorical features?

In fact, based on this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab), the association between categorical variables should be computed using Crammer's V. Therefore, I found the following [code](https://www.kaggle.com/phaethonprime/eda-and-logistic-regression) to plot it, but I don't know why he plotted it for "contribution", which is a numeric variable?

```
def cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_matrix):
    """ calculate Cramers V statistic for categorical-categorical association.
        uses correction from Bergsma and Wicher, 
        Journal of the Korean Statistical Society 42 (2013): 323-328
    """
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))    
    rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))


cols = ["Party", "Vote", "contrib"]
corrM = np.zeros((len(cols),len(cols)))
# there's probably a nice pandas way to do this
for col1, col2 in itertools.combinations(cols, 2):
    idx1, idx2 = cols.index(col1), cols.index(col2)
    corrM[idx1, idx2] = cramers_corrected_stat(pd.crosstab(df[col1], df[col2]))
    corrM[idx2, idx1] = corrM[idx1, idx2]

corr = pd.DataFrame(corrM, index=cols, columns=cols)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 6))
ax = sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True, ax=ax); ax.set_title("Cramer V Correlation between Variables");
```

I also found [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html). However, I am not sure if it uses Crammer's V to plot the `heatmap` or not?

Really, I have two categorical features: the first one has 2 categories and the second one has 37 categories.

I need the plot will be like the two last plots presented [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html), but also display the association values on it too.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be useful to plot the relationship between categorical features. The visualization would imply an ordering to categorical values which might not lead to incorrect interpretations.

A more useful option might be a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table). One feature would be in the rows, another feature would be in the columns. The cells would be the counts of co-occurrence.