# Correlation between nominal categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, correlation

I have two arrays, whose values are nominal categorical variables. Each element represents a zone of a city: in the first vector we have the class each zone belongs to (so these might also be seen as ordinal, since values span from 0 to 3, with 3 being the upper class -let's say richest- and 0 the poorest, but I am not sure about this). The second vector is made of names: each item is the name of the candidate who won the Presidential elections in that particular zone.

I would like to calculate the correlation between the two vectors, to find whether there is some kind of relationship between the *class* of the zone and the winning candidate (i.e. candidate *X* systematically won in the poorest zones), but I am not sure on how to calculate correlation between nominal variables. I found [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab) somewhat helpful, but the example provided in the answer does not match with my case.

Answer (score 1):

The Chi-Squared test of independence (and subsequent Cramer's V test) give an indication of the relationship between two categorical variables.

Answer (score 0):

Chi-Square is used to check whether any two categorical variables are independent. Ordinal is also categorical,  so we can use it for the same. You can find my answer to a similar question [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51591/what-measures-can-i-use-to-find-correlation-between-categorical-features-and-bin/51635#51635).

The only difference will be that you will change the $O_{ij}$ (Observed count of data points with the $i$th category of the first variable and $j$th category of the second variable) in the contingency table and corresponding $E_{ij}$ will change accordingly.

Once you have the contingency table, you can use R to find the association between those two variables.

Comment: Careful using this for ordinal variables. There are better alternatives.