# Is numpy.corrcoef() enough to find correlation?

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, numpy, kaggle

I am currently working through Kaggle's titanic competition and I'm trying to figure out the correlation between the `Survived` column and other columns.  I am using `numpy.corrcoef()` to matrix the correlation between the columns and here is what I have:

```
The correlation between pClass & Survived is: [[ 1.         -0.33848104]
 [-0.33848104  1.        ]]

The correlation between Sex & Survived is: [[ 1.         -0.54335138]
 [-0.54335138  1.        ]]

The correlation between Age & Survived is:[[ 1.         -0.07065723]
 [-0.07065723  1.        ]]

The correlation between Fare & Survived is: [[1.         0.25730652]
 [0.25730652 1.        ]]

The correlation between Parent-Children & Survived is: [[1.         0.08162941]
 [0.08162941 1.        ]]

The correlation between Sibling-Spouse & Survived is: [[ 1.        -0.0353225]
 [-0.0353225  1.       ]]

The correlation between Embarked & Survived is: [[ 1.         -0.16767531]
 [-0.16767531  1.        ]]
```

There should be higher correlation between `Survived` and [`pClass`, `sex`, `Sibling-Spouse`] and yet the values are really low.  I'm new to this so I understand that a simple method is not the best way to find correlations but at the moment, this doesn't add up.

This is my full code (without the `printf()` calls):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Titanic-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

survived = train['Survived']
pClass = train['Pclass']
sex = train['Sex'].replace(['female', 'male'], [0, 1])
age = train['Age'].fillna(round(float(np.mean(train['Age'].dropna()))))
fare = train['Fare']
parch = train['Parch']
sibSp = train['SibSp']
embarked = train['Embarked'].replace(['C', 'Q', 'S'], [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: why do you think the values should be higher?

Comment: Because there is a strong correlation between sex, class and survival.  Women and rich passengers were most likely to survive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a side note, I don't think correlation is the correct measure of relation for you to be using, since `Survived` is technically a binary categorical variable.

"Correlation" measures used should depend on the type of variables being investigated:

1. continuous variable v continuous variable: use "traditional" correlation - e.g. Spearman's rank correlation or Pearson's linear correlation.
2. continuous variable v categorical variable: use an ANOVA F-test / difference of means
3. categorical variable v categorical variable: use Chi-square / Cramer's V

Comment: Here is a closely related [old post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/893/67328).

Comment: @bradS When you say `ANOVA F-test/difference of means`, do you mean dividing ANOVA F-test by difference of means?

Comment: @AtillaAdrianopolos, no I mean "/" as "or". Using item 3 above as an example, use Chi-square test of independence _or_ Cramer's V.

Answer (score 1):

You probably encoded *Women* as 0 and men as 1 that's why you get a negative correlation of -0.54, because *Survived* is 0 for No and 1 for Yes. Your calculation actually show what you've expected. The negative correlation is only about the direction depending on your encoding, the relationship between *Women* and *Survived* is 0.54.

Similarly *pClass* is correlated negatively with -0.33 because the highest class (1st class) is encoded as 1 and the lowest as 3, thus the direction is negative.

You could make the relations more intuitive if you make new columns for men and women where you put 0 and 1 depending on the sex, then the correlations will have the intuitive direction (sign). The same holds for *pClass*.

Comment: I've added my code.

Comment: What if I encode `male/female` with `3/4` instead?  They're still binary values and just might solve the problem you're raisng.